# Converting Spring xml config to java

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I've an XML config for mail service in spring, that I'd like to transform to JAVA config.

XML Looks like this

```
<int:chain id="chain"
           input-channel="outMailError"
    output-channel="outMailEntry">
    <int:poller max-messages-per-poll="1" fixed-rate="20000" />
    <int:transformer ref="mailSendErrorTransformer" />
</int:chain>

<int:channel id="outMailError">
    <int:queue capacity="500" />
</int:channel>

<int:channel id="outboundMailEntry" />
```

I was able to convert the channels to

```
@Bean
public DirectChannel outboundMailEntry() {
    return new DirectChannel();
}

@Bean
public QueueChannel outboundMailErrorChannel() {
    return new QueueChannel(500);
}
```

But I don't know how to the same for int:chain. I was able to debug and find out what type of bean does spring instantiate for "chain" part of xml - it is `PollingConsumer` that takes 2 params `PollableChannel inputChannel, MessageHandler handler`.

The first one is not a problem since I already have that, it is the

```
@Qualifier("outMailError")
QueueChannel channel
```

But I do not know about the second one... Spring itself initializes some `MessageHandlerChain` but I was unable to to set the `outMailEntry` to it and also dont know about the poller and transformer.. any ídeas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `chain`  equivalent in Java Config. It was designed especially for XML to let to minimize XML coding.

On the other hand it doesn't look like you need that `<chain>` at all: you have only one `<int:transformer>` over there.

In Java Config you would use a `@Trasnoformer` annotation on your `mailSendErrorTransformer` method with appropriate `inputChannel` and `outputChannel` attributes. The `<int:poller>` equivalent is also present over there as a `poller` attribute with resective `@Poller` configuration.

See more info in the docs starting from here:  https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/overview.html#configuration-enable-integration

Comment: thank you, one more thing if you could help me... what about config such as this?

 <int:header-enricher input-channel="outboundMail"
  output-channel="outboundMailEntry">
  <int:error-channel ref="outboundMailErrorChannel" />
 </int:header-enricher>

I think I should convert it to import org.springframework.integration.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer?

Comment: See `@ServiceActivator` on `@Bean` method and `DefaultHeaderEnricher`. Of course it even would be better to go Java DSL... everything is in that doc